# Pointer Initialization (char and int)

Tags: c, pointers, initialization

In C language if

```
char *ptr1 = "something";
```

is allowed, then why not

```
int *ptr2 = {1,2,3};
```

not allowed?

Comment: It's the way the language is designed. But admittedly this would be a useful feature of the language.

Comment: Simply put, a string literal is an array object, while `{1,2,3}` is just an initializer list. You can point to the first object of an array, but you can't point at an initializer list.

Answer (score 4):

In the first case,

```
 char *ptr1 = "something";
```

`"something"` boils down to a pointer to the first element, of the string literal, yields a type `char*`, so the type is compatible and assignment in the initialization is valid.

On the other hand,

```
int *ptr2 = {1,2,3};
```

`{1,2,3}` is a brace enclosed initializer list, not an `int *`, so it's invalid operation and not allowed.

What you can do, actually is to use a [compound literal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_syntax#Compound_literals) for the intialization, something like

```
int *ptr2 = (int []){1,2,3};
```

where `ptr2` will point to the first element of the array composed of the values given in the brace enclosed initializer list.

Comment: But watch out for the lifetime of the array: "If the compound literal occurs outside the body of a function, the object has static storage duration; otherwise, it has automatic storage duration associated with the enclosing block."

Comment: @rici true that. I considered OP was more concerned about the syntax and that's what I tried addressing in the answer. A very welcome comment, nonetheless.